# Username format in HTTP Authorization request header

Tags: http, authorization

According to [RFC2617](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617#page-17) `authorization request header` contains `username, realm, response` etc. My question is about `username` field.

Username has two formats available

```
1. "username" 
2. "username@domain"
```

But how could I know which format need to use. Some server support first one and other support 2nd format.

## realm

A string to be displayed to users so they know which username and password to use.

## username

The user's name in the specified realm.

So how could I determine which username format to use from realm?